# CPU Usage 100% when creating 3 threads and using WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() and WSAEnumNetworkEvents()

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, events

I have created 3 threads each thread has one socket each. 
Inside each thread, socket is made "Event Driven" and whenever data becomes available for reading, an event is generated.

The code works fine but it takes CPU Usage upto 100% which is surely undesirable. I think I have made some mistake. Below is my code. Please help me in figuring out what mistake have I made that results in 100% CPU Usage.

**Code:**

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID param)
{
   int threadNumber= (int)param;
   int PORT = 8888+threadNumber; //so that each thread bind()s its socket to a different Port number.
   WSADATA wsa; 

   //Initialise winsock//
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
      {

        //"WinSock Initialization FAILED",

      }

   //Create a socket//

  SOCKET newSocketIdentifier;
  SOCKADDR_IN newSocket;

  if((newSocketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {                 

        //Socket Creation Failed

      }
   //Socket Created//

   //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure//
  newSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
  newSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  newSocket.sin_port = htons(PORT);

   //Bind//
   if( bind(newSocketIdentifier ,(struct sockaddr *)&newSocket, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      { 
       //Bind Failed
      }

   //Bind Done//
char data[256];
int bytes, waitRet;

WSAEVENT hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSANETWORKEVENTS events;
WSAEventSelect(newSocketIdentifier, hEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE);

   while(1)
      {
         waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, &hEvent, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
         if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(newSocketIdentifier,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            //Error
         else
            {
               if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
                  {
                      //call recvfrom()
                  }
            }
      }

    WSACloseEvent(hEvent);
   return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd )
{

   HANDLE threadHandle[3];
   DWORD threadId = 0;
   int max_number=3;
   //Start the threads
   for (int i = 0; i < max_number; i++) 
   {
    threadHandle[i]= CreateThread( NULL,
                                       0,
                                       ThreadProc,
                                       (LPVOID) i,
                                       0,
                                       NULL
                                 );
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont have idea on windows sockets or programming. Experts in this could give you better ideas. Meanwhile, you could try this. Inside the while loop, use any blocking call that would wait for some event to occur. Here, just ensure WSAWaitForMultipleEvents or WSAEnumNetworkEvents would block atleast for some time. May be it is blocking already ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error:

```
waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, &hEvent, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
```

as it is stating there are two events in the supplied event array, which is not the case as there is only 1. From the [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219(v=vs.85).aspx) reference page describing the first argument:

> The number of event object handles in the array pointed to by lphEvents. The maximum number of event object handles is WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS. One or more events must be specified.

I suspect that this causing undefined behaviour as `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` is accessing beyond the bounds of the array, probably causing the function to not block resulting in the busy loop.

Additionally, see answer from [Rohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229410/rohan) regarding usage of `WSAResetEvent()`.

Comment: +1 for the answer as it solved the problem :) but still I don't understand the issue. According to my understanding, there are two events i.e. FD_READ and FD_Write :( Am I wrong? :(

Comment: There are two events in which you are interested, but only 1 event handle that is gong to be triggered for both. If you wish to separate these two use one event handle per event.

Comment: hmjd is mostly right, except that you can't actually separate the read and write events for the same socket. If you call WSAEventSelect again with that socket, it clears any previous events tied to that socket. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898740.aspx) : `Issuing a WSAEventSelect call for a socket cancels any previous WSAEventSelect calls for the same socket and clears the internal network event record.`